# How to check if picture exists in item display template?

Tags: display-template

I tried to check in my custom item display template if a picture exists by url. Sometimes the site Logo is set to some path of an picture, but the picture doesn't exist anymore. I would like to replace it with a default picture.

**UPDATE!**

I try already code below but got an error:

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is
>   denied.

The url of the picture (`http://myCompany.com/sites/jantje/PublishingImages/right_folder_arrow_move_archive.png`) is inside the current website, but is not existed because it is already removed.

```
    var noPictureFoundImgUrl = "/_layouts/15/Images/MyCompany.Intranet/default.png"

    var imageUrl = null;

    if ($isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.SiteLogo))
    {
        imageUrl = noPictureFoundImgUrl;
    }
    else
    {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('HEAD', ctx.CurrentItem.SiteLogo, false);
        http.send();

        // check if sitelogo exists
        if(http.status != 404)
        {
            imageUrl = ctx.CurrentItem.SiteLogo;
        }
        else
        {
            imageUrl = noPictureFoundImgUrl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about using $.get jquery function https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ . You can check whether the request failed or succeeded and  run your logic accordingly

Comment: I got an access denied error.

Comment: check my answer for an alternative approach.

Comment: which answer do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest()` to check if image exists.

```
function imageExists(image_url){

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', image_url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status != 404;

}
```

So in your display template, you can update it as below

```
// check if sitelogo exists
if(imageExists(pictureUrl))
{
    imageUrl = pictureUrl;
}
else
{
    imageUrl = noPictureFoundImgUrl;
}
```

Also you can use **jQuery** `$.get`.

```
$.get(pictureUrl)
.done(function() { 
    // Do something now you know the image exists.
    imageUrl = pictureUrl;

}).fail(function() { 
    // Image doesn't exist - do something else.
    imageUrl = noPictureFoundImgUrl;
})
```

Refer [Check if image exists on server using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837735/check-if-image-exists-on-server-using-javascript)

Comment: See my update. I try your solution but got an access denied exception.

Comment: @Ola What value do you have in `ctx.CurrentItem.SiteLogo`

Comment: http://myCompany.com/sites/jantje/PublishingImages/right_folder_arrow_move_archive.png

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onError` event of the `img` tag, one example:

```
<img src="expectedimage.gif" alt="Expected Image not found" onError="this.src='defaultImage.gif';" />
```

This topic has been discussed in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984287/how-to-show-alternate-image-if-source-image-is-not-found-onerror-working-in-ie) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images).

Comment: I dont using <img> but I use a div with a background image. I try the onError solution on a div, but it didnt work. <div class="cbs-pictureOnTopImageContainer" style="background-image: url(_#= imageUrl =#_);" id="_#= pictureContainerId =#_" onError="this.src = '_#= noPictureFoundImgUrl =#_';"></div>

Comment: div doesnt have an onerror event. In this case you can try specifying your noPictureFoundImgUrl in the backgroung image property such as: background-image: url('expectedimageurl'), url('noPictureFoundImgUrl');